# Select specific row with applying a condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL variable `variants` which holds a data like this

```
    <syddata lastUpdated="30.10.2013 05:50 ">
  <data itemnumber="sd20-grøn-200cm" variant1="Grøn" variant2="140x200 cm"  var1code="gron" var2code="200cm"></data>
  <data itemnumber="sd20-grøn-220cm" variant1="Grøn" variant2="140x220 cm"  var1code="gron" var2code="220cm" ></data>
  <data itemnumber="sd20-grå-200cm" variant1="Grå" variant2="140x200 cm" var1code="graa" var2code="200cm" ></data>
  <data itemnumber="sd20-grå-220cm" variant1="Grå" variant2="140x220 cm"  var1code="graa" var2code="220cm"></data>
</syddata>
```

Now I want to select a specific row from this ,a row where `variant1="Grå"` and `variant2="140x200 cm"`  I have tried comething like this

```
<xsl:if test="$variants/syddata/data/@variant1 = 'Grå'  and $variants/syddata/data/@variant2 = '140x200 cm'">
        <xsl:value-of select="@itemnumber"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

But its not giving me anything.Can any one tell me whats the correct way to implement this logic in XSLT

Comment: When you say a variable "which holds a data like this", is that a node set selected out of the input document or is it nested XML like `<xsl:variable name="variants"><syddata ...`?

Comment: @IanRoberts its a node set selected from another document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test

```
$variants/syddata/data/@variant1 = 'Grå'  and
 $variants/syddata/data/@variant2 = '140x200 cm'
```

simply checks whether there is a `data` element with `variant1="Grå"` and also a `data` element (not necessarily the same one) with `variant2="140x200 cm"`.  If you want to check both conditions on *the same* `data` element, and then extract its itemnumber, you'd need something more like

```
<xsl:variable name="item"
   select="$variants/syddata/data[@variant1='Grå' and @variant2='140x200 cm']" />
<xsl:if test="$item"><xsl:value-of select="$item/@itemnumber" /></xsl:if>
```